# Unable to delete directory: F:\AS_Pro\Grocehop\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\android\support\graphics\drawable\animated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The animated folder contains three class files:**R$dimen.class**, **R$drawable.class**,
**R$id.class**.

1. Tried **rebuilding** the project..it did not work.
2. While i tried **gradlew clean** from the terminal..it could not delete.
3. Went to the folder location and tried deleting it **manually**..it displayed a dialog box with an error "Error 0x80070570: the file or directory is corrupted
   and unreadable"

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you so much.

Comment: Try deleting/moving that file manually, before you delete/move close android studio and make sure you have killed java from Task Manager/System Monitor

Comment: @Prashant Yeah i did... stopped all the processes by this taskkill /F /IM java.exe.And after that reached the destination folder and tried deleteing it. The dialog box appeared with the above mentioned error.

Comment: Have you tried moving those files? if you can move, move files to parent directory(only one level at once). and try deleting it after moving out of project folder.

Comment: @Prashant I am sorry for the delay in reply. I tried moving them and again a dialog box pops up with the same error. Anything else that can be done?

Comment: I can not find any option other than try running disk check utility and check if disk is faulty. Make sure that you backup important data.

Comment: @Prashant My other android projects in the same disk work fine.Compile and run. Only one of the project has this issue.

Comment: Sometimes only some sectors of the disk gets damaged and not whole disk.
data written on bad sectors can not be read afterwards. I had similar problem in which my project folder was inaccessible , whenever i try to access those file, system will hang. after running disk check i came to know the issue, Disk check won't alter any data but i would suggest you to backup important file because if this is the issue, you don't loose other data. Right now i can not guess any other issues for this cause.